# Rails3 Active Record Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have Messages and User models with corresponding tables.
The Messages table has such fields like user_from and user_to.

How can associate the models to be able to access sender and recipient users objects:

```
message.user_from.name
message.user_to.id
...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full solution for my case is:

```
  belongs_to :sender, 
    :class_name => "User", 
    :foreign_key => "sender_id", 
    **:primary_key => "uid"**

  belongs_to :recipient, 
    :class_name => "User", 
    :foreign_key => "recipient_uid", 
    **:primary_key => "uid"**
```

because user id was not primary key in User table.

Answer (score 2):

you need to update your message model like this:

```
belongs_to :user_from, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :user_to, :class_name => "User"
```

This wil create the corresponding fields under message table that links to User table via their ids.

Comment: you meant belongs_to I guess. still it will not work if table columns storing foreign keys are also called  user_from and user_to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
This is actually what I did and it does not work. But I think it correct solutions and I have some other mistakes in my code or DB.

I'm using SQLight on my dev machin. Should I have foreign keys defined to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

if you db stores user ids as foreign keys in the messages table, you cannot use the same name for the association. But you could say:

```
class Message
  belongs_to :from, class: 'User', foreign_key: :user_from
  belongs_to :to, class: 'User', foreign_key: :user_from
end
```

in rails, it is best practice to use `<assiciation_name>_id` as the foreign key column name, then you can use simply

```
class Message
  belongs_to :user_from, class: 'User' # foreign_key: :user_from_id by default
  belongs_to :user_to, class: 'User' # foreign_key: :user_to_id by default
end
```